# Consistency for read from distributed databases

Tags: distributed-computing, eventual-consistency, distributed-database, data-consistency

I have a set of databases, distributed across multiple locations in the network and for ex. one client that needs to store some data in that databases.

I need to make sure my data will always be stored.

I can't organize a replica set with sync/async replication as it will make me to connect to one master which is a point of failure, so I send data from the client to all databases I know. Apparently, one database can fail to store, so I am relying on other databases writes. In the end I get different data sets stored in DB's though these sets are overlapping. (Ex. DB1 -> [1, 2, 3], DB2 -> [1, 3], DB3 -> [2,3,4])

How can get consistent data when reading from these DBs? What techniques should I apply on the client that writes data and a client that reads to be able to merge data sets successfully (getting on reader [1,2,3,4])?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is basically an entire branch of computer science. It is very much a non-trivial problem and you will find that a surprising number of things are impossible.

Also note that simply saying "consistent" data is not a sufficient definition. There are all sorts of levels of consistency (read-your-own-writes, reads-follow-writes, monotonic read, linearizable, causal, etc.) I think you likely mean (in a very loose sense): consistency similar to what you get when you use just one database.

To answer your question directly, you want to decide on a read quorum size and a write quorum size. These sizes must be selected such that reads and writes will overlap by at least one database instance. If you want to optimize for write latency, use a smaller write quorum and do the opposite if you want to optimize for read latency.

A more detailed exposition of overlapping read/write quorums can be found in [Weighted Voting for Replicated Data](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.12.6256). This is considered a seminal work in the field of replication.

Also be careful around the behavior of your overlapping quorums when adding or removing a database instance. It sounds like you have a relatively static topology, but if that is not the case, then an entirely different set of choices need to be made.

Lastly - and here's the real kick in the teeth - what I have described doesn't actually give you consistency (by any definition) in some cases (I like [Daniel Abadi's explanation of when andy why](http://dbmsmusings.blogspot.com/2012/10/ieee-computer-issue-on-cap-theorem.html?showComment=1353363529247#c8721474304375616864)), but for many systems it gives you *good enough* consistency. It's up to you to decide exactly what level of consistency you need.

Comment: Thanks for a good reply. I've read Werner's article about types of eventual consistency, where he talks about read-your-own-writes, monotonic read and etc. This is all about replica set EC, so that each instance will eventually get the same data as others. I probably don't need that as the main purpose of that storage is low write latency, I just want to be able to read from all nodes and recreate data set which has been sent from the client. For now I see a solution that I assign number to each batch I send out to the nodes so later on a reader I can detect unique data items.

Comment: I see. I mistook the thrust of your question a bit. You might look into using vector clocks as a method of detection conflicts. The question then becomes fashioning a deterministic merge function to apply at read-time (i.e. read-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

There are two-way/three-way replication software that do not require a "master". 
You can also use transaction log based replications.

What and how you can use will depend on the database product you use.

HTH